# Accidentally typed node . instead of code . to open VS Code via WSL and it's not opening VS Code now

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I accidentally typed `node .` instead of `code .` to open VS Code via WSL and when I typed `code .` again it will not open VS Code no more.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  After typing `code .` normally it will return a new line for you to type command in and also open VS code, and now it's just showing the user@LAPTOP-xxxxx:~$ to get you to type in command.  Please help, thanks.

Comment: after reading: `Type ".help" for more information.` you should have typed `.help`.  Now use `.exit` to get back to your Linux prompt

Comment: When I typed .help, I'm getting 'Command '.help' not found, did you mean:
  command 'dhelp' from deb dhelp (0.6.27)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>'  and then when I typed .exit, it says  .exit: command not found                                                                                                                                    I have tried opening vs code from Windows and it's showing WSL:Ubuntu-22.04 extension but  just no luck opening VS Code from WSL/Ubuntu terminal with code .

Comment: so you are back on the prompt that shows a `$` ?  Than `code .` should get you where the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode#open-a-wsl-project-in-visual-studio-code) say you would go.

Comment: Yes, I'm back on the prompt that shows a $ but nothing happens when I type code .     I don't know if when I typed node . by mistake that that has affected it and WSL/Ubuntu will not open VS Code after typing code .

Comment: When you type `whereis code` you should see: `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code`. When that is not the case your installation is broken. (Which has nothing to do with the `node .` command you typed)

Comment: Hi Luuk, I have typed whereis code and it is showing exactly as the file path that you have shown so i guess the installation is not broken yet.  It was since yesterday, after I mistakenly typed node . and then code . just doesn't work and it will just go to the next prompt $ as usual with no error shown and without opening VS Code.

Comment: @Hamu1160 My first troubleshooting step with VSCode issues in WSL is to remove the VSCode server directory -- `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server`.  It does not contain anything "permanent" and will be regenerated the next time you run `code` from WSL, but you are welcome to back it up or rename it first if you prefer.

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds thanks for your reply.  I was also waiting for reply from VSCode team on github before trying your method but when I typed code . again yesterday  and it seemed to updated VSCode version as well and it seemed to work then which opened VSCode.   Next time if I encounter similar problem, I'll use your troubleshooting step, thanks again.